# Sql query solution needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in the following format

```
ID    class       indicator
1      A              Y
1      B              N 
1      C(recent)      N
2      X              N
2      K(recent)      N
```

if a particular ID has its recent class indicator as N then search if it was Y somewhere before that recent entry if yes then answer should be that class if not then the recent entry is the answer.

Example: for ID 1 the recent entry was C but we got a Y at A also so we have to return A but in ID 2, K is the recent entry and we don't have any Y indicator before that so we should return Y.

Comment: A solution is "needed" but what have you discovered or attempted? What efforts have you made?

Comment: I think rather than finding a sql solution for this, you should seriously consider modifying that data structure, because it's not a good one. You should not be including "recent" in the class column. You should be using some date column or some other identifier in a different column.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to sort the entries for each ID according to this logic, assign a number to each with `row_number()` and take just the first:

```
SELECT id, class, indicator
FROM   (SELECT id, class, indicator,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                  ORDER BY indicator DESC,
                                           CASE WHEN class LIKE '%(recent)'  THEN 0
                                                                             ELSE 1
                                           END ASC) AS rn
        FROM mytable) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: if i add dates instead of class then how should i proceed?

Comment: @NewBie I don't understand this question. Can you perhaps clarify with an example?

Comment: why did you not mention that in your question ? You have us all look for something else than what you want now

Answer (score 1):

in your comment with Mureinik's answer you mention you want to use a datetime column in stead of `recent`in the class column.

One way to do this is like below, but this will not perform great if you have really many records

your table would look sometimes like this in that case :

```
ID  Class   Indicator   IndicatorDate   
--  -----   ---------   -------------   
1   A       Y           31/03/2018 12:59:18 
1   B       N            1/04/2018 12:59:18 
1   C       N            3/04/2018 12:59:18 
2   X       N            3/04/2018 12:59:18 
2   K       N            2/04/2018 12:59:18
```

and a possible solution would be this

```
declare @table table (ID int, Class varchar(1), Indicator varchar(1), IndicatorDate datetime)

insert into @Table(ID, Class, Indicator, IndicatorDate)
values (1, 'A', 'Y', getdate() - 3), (1, 'B', 'N', getdate() - 2), (1,  'C', 'N', getdate()), (2, 'X', 'N', getdate()), (2, 'K', 'N', getdate() - 1)

select td.ID,
       (select top 1 t2.Class from @table t2 where t2.ID = td.ID order by t2.Indicator desc, t2.IndicatorDate desc) as selectedClass,
       (select top 1 t2.Indicator from @table t2 where t2.ID = td.ID order by t2.Indicator desc, t2.IndicatorDate desc) as selectedIndicator
from 
(  select distinct t.ID
   from   @table t
) td
```

which would return this

```
ID  selectedClass   selectedIndicator   
--  -------------   -----------------   
1   A               Y   
2   X               N
```

HOWEVER:
This depends on if the endresult of this query is really what you are looking for, its still not entirely clear to me